# Stating that you like to watch a certain TV show

Tags: word-order

How can I answer the question “Was für Fernsehprogramme sehen Sie gern?”, if I want to say for example that I like to watch Family Guy.

I want to answer using a complete sentence.

So can I say the following?

> Ich sehe gern Family Guy.

Comment: The translation is correct, but this is not a very general question that may be of interest for other users.

Comment: vote for reopen. The question is okay and the answer of @Medi1Saif is interesting.

Comment: @Iris I disagree. The question still reads like proofreading. Medi’s answer *is* interesting, but not for a proofreading question imho.

Answer (score 2):

As an answer:

> Ich sehe gern Family Guy.

is absolutely correct.

But here are other options:

> Ich *schaue* gerne Family Guy.

with the Verb *schauen* instead of *sehen*.

> Ich *sehe* mir gerne Family Guy *an*.

with *mir* and the Verbs *anschauen*/*angucken*/*ansehen*.

> Ich *verfolge die Serie* Family Guy.

an option with a totally different sentence and other meaning (@Iris thanks for the remark!) as the focus is nor more on what you like to see then on how regular do you watch a special series! 
Of course if we go further we can build much more sentences which may partly answer the question but include further information, therefor this answer is fine, but maybe a bit misleading, and should be considered as an outlook for further improvement!

Comment: "Ich verfolge die Serie Family Guy." means that I want to be up to date with the plot of the series. That could mean that I love it and watch it regularly but it can also be a statement without rating. An example: "Vor Wahlen verfolge ich die Nachrichten regelmäßiger als sonst."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is correct to say " ich sehe gern Family guy". You can also use "ich liebe es Family guy im Fernsehen zu schauen.

Comment: Well your addition is not that correct you'd rather say: Ich liebe *es* Familiy guy im Fernsehen (*an*) zu schauen.

Comment: You corrected my sentence nicely. Good job !